# How do I play .swf files?

Tags: video, swf

Does anyone know what libraries I have to install to play .swf files?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the standalone flashplayer by Adobe :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FlashPlayerStandalone

But you can also open the file in your Internet browser if you have installed flash plugin.

Comment: Ok, I guess I had some sort of configuration problem.  When I tried to install the flash plug-in into my browser it said it was already installed, but I still couldn't play the videos.  An uninstall/reinstall fixed my problem.

Comment: It did not work when I tried to open my swf on chrome.

Comment: If Googlers don't want to do this accepted answer, check out this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/467892/374783

Comment: @Anderson, as far as I can tell your link no longer offers a download nor does the one in the answer.

Comment: Please ignore today answers that were written more than a decade ago. There is very little chance that they are still relevant. I think StackOverflow should just archive this stuff.

Answer (score 30):

Sorry, that didn't post right.

Edit **/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml** file and change

```
<mime-type type="application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie">
```

to

```
<mime-type type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

and then run

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

and then reinstall flash player.

Comment: The real solution to play `swf` (shockwave flash) files in browsers while they just save or ask to save local `swf` files. (Pushing some keywords here.)

Comment: No need to reinstall flash player here. After updating mime database it works.

Comment: this works like a charm..

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/478169/why-cant-firefox-run-local-swf-files

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 + Chrome. It works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope, this didn't work - the videos don't run. `gnash` did the job well though.

Comment: Didn't work on Ubuntu 17.10 :( gnash can't play games, only videos.

Answer (score 30):

`.swf` files can be opened with `gnash` swf viewer. If you don't have it:

```
sudo apt-get install gnash
```

Comment: Its good but not support Persian or Arabic lang.

Comment: I do not know however where the Gnash is officially developed and where one should sent suggestions (like Persian and Arabic language support above).
On the github https://github.com/strk/gnash , or at savannah http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/gnash/  ? At the first one there are some commits from 2016, but the second one seems to be outdated. In my Ubuntu LTS there is version 0.8.11alpha while the github has a README of 0.8.8.

Comment: Not in 20.04 anymore https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnash :-( https://askubuntu.com/questions/619849/how-to-download-gnash-swf-player-from-ubuntu-centre-to-synaptic-manager

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is going to the adobe [site](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) and then selecting

Download the Flash Player Projector (64-bit)

Then extract the contents,inside the extracted folder there is a file called flashplayer open it. Then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the file locally isntead of typing it as a url.

Comment: The download link is broken, showing an end-of-life page. But the site link works, and I could still download the player projector from there.

Answer (score 2):

Just found worked solution to play flash with firefox from [ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2386372&p=13745872#post13745872)

Here are steps in resume:

Create file `~/.mime.types` with content:

```
application/x-shockwave-flash       swf swfl
```

Disable setting `plugins.http_https_only` (make it equal to false) in firefox by typing: `about:config` in URL box and finding this setting with `Ctrl+f`.

Now you can open .swf file from file manager by Open With Firefox. Or open it from firefox with `Ctrl+o`.

PS. you'll need to accept the warning about *accept the risk* and restart firefox once setting is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

## How to open a .swf-file with Firefox browser

Right-click on the file. Choose `Properties > Open With`, then click on `show other applications`. Now you can add `firefox` in the list. Set it as default. Now double-click on the `.swf`-file.

It will open in the Firefox and play itself. I assume the flashplayer-plugin is already installed in Firefox, else it will ask you to install flashplayer-plugin. Follow the steps and you are good to go.

Comment: This answer does not work in the latest version of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Install `swfdec-gnome`

```
sudo apt-get install swfdec-gnome
```

Use latest Google Chrome (which has inbuilt flash support)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/152976/68508

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you do not want to open it in web browser is you can install shockwave player for windows in Ubuntu via wine. I installed it and it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In order to locally open `.swf` file with more recent Firefox versions
(`78+`), old methods wouldn't work, e. g. changing/replacing entries of
`application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie` with appropriate entries for `application/x-shockwave-flash` (or creating the latter, where the former was missing).

**Tried modifications:**

- installing `flashplayer-mozilla` package
- in FF' `about:config`, setting `plugins.http_https_only` to `false`
- in FF' Shockwave Flash plugin's settings, enabling `alays ask`
- applying the above in FF' profile folder's 'mimeTypes.rdf'
- creating file
  *~/.mime.types* with entry:

  `application/x-shockwave-flash                   swf swfl`
- replacing `vnd.adobe.flash.movie` with that entry in `/etc/mime.types`
- replacing/adding an appropriate entry for
  `<mime-type type="application/x-shockwave-flash">` to
  */usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml*
- executing mandatory `update-mime-database /usr/share/mime`

So, even with `xdg-mime query default application/...` pointing to
Firefox' corresponding `.desktop` starter configuration file, for both
mime types, and FF correctly showing a choice to execute '*.swf' with
Flash Player, it failed.

**SOLUTION:**

As it turned out, the following steps were required, to finally be able
to execute local `.swf` files in Firefox (with some of the above maybe
still required beforehand):

1. Replace following entry in FF profile folder's file ***handlers.json***
   (mind replacing exactly between the correct 2 commata!)

   `application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie`

   with

   `"application/x-shockwave-flash":{"action":2,"handlers":[{"name":"flashplayer","path":"/usr/lib/flashplayer-mozilla/libflashplayer.so"}],"extensions":["swf"],"ask":true}`
2. Re-install `flashplayer-mozilla` package
3. Disconnect from the network **(!)**
4. Temporarily reset the desktop's system date, back to before the official EoL date (*< December 31, 2020*) of FlashPlayer, or else it will attempt redirecting to Adobe's EoL website **(!)**
5. Now finally 'enjoy' playing your favorite local SWF / FlashPlayer files!
6. After finished, restore the original system date **(!)**

**NOTE:**
There might be a problem with all add-on's disabled after a restart, if
restoring the original system date before hasn't occured before
(or while FF trying to update its components, unless disabled before).

To fix this, reset all of Firefox' registry entries, starting with
`app.update.lastUpdateTime*`.

**P.S.:**
It might be arguably a 'good idea', to store away a copy of the last version
(*32.0 r0 / 32.0.0.465*) of Shockwave Flash player's binary from
*/usr/lib/flashplayer-mozilla/libflashplayer.so* - you never know, it
might vanish from the repositories someday. But then, Mozilla could also blacklist the plugin completely.

Also, if somehow it doesn't work out, you might check for the following
registered mime type in the `Shockwave Flash` plugin's settings in FF:
`application/x-shockwave-flash (Shockwave Flash: swf)`

And in `about:preferences#general` Applications, search for 'Flash'; it
should show `Flashplayer | always ask`.

To execute a local `.swf` files, you'll have to click through several
security warning popups (2-4), each time, especially, with `NoScript`.

**ATTENTION:**
Due to the notorious security problems history with Flash Player, use this method at your own risk! It's generally a bad idea, and most especially, to download new `.swf` files from dubious websites and executing them. This method should be used with caution, and only if you **'know what you're doing' !**

Answer (score 0):

In 22.04 you can install Adobe Flash Player from the software center:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you need an old version of Adobe Flash Player (before they were self-sabotaged to stop working after a certain time).

It is available here: https://archive.org/details/flashplayer_32_sa_202104

Similarly you can use old versions of browser plugins to make flash work in a browsers. E.g.: https://archive.org/details/flashplayer_old

(Thank god for the archive.org)

---

Works on Dec 26 2023