# Unable to open local .swf in any browser

Tags: firefox, flash, chromium, mime-type

When trying to open locally saved .swf (any) in Chromium or Firefox instead of opening it browser opens save prompt.
Flash plugin is installed for both, flash is working when viewed embedded into .html. mime-type fix (vnd.adobe.something ⇒ x-shockwave-flash) applied.
Everything was working fine around 2017 New Year when I last tried opening .swf successfully, afterwards I had several dist-upgrades -y, but nothing drastic.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make it work in Firefox:

- I followed the steps written in https://askubuntu.com/a/555559/286232
- I executed
  `sudo apt install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the Flash Player Projector to play local swf files.
https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html