# How to download GNASH SWF Player from Ubuntu Centre to Synaptic Manager?

Tags: software-center, plugins

As suggested by the Software Center, I have selected GNASH SWF Player for a plugin to view certain media on my browser, but, I do not know how to download this player from my browser to the Synaptic Manager to get it installed for viewing media files from my browser?

How do I do this?

Comment: 2 answers, but neither work on ubuntu18.10

Comment: superset: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7240/how-do-i-play-swf-files

Answer (score 0):

**Usgin Command Line:**

open  your terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnash
```

you'll be asked for your password, then enter it and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Once it's finished then you already installed gnash swf.

**Using GUI:**

From Dash search for Ubuntu software Center then open it.

In the search field on the right top corner search for the key word `gnash`

[image]

Now click on the gnash swf entry, you can see like this picture notice that there now exist a button install

[image]

Press the button install and wait a little you notice that install changes to remove and there is a green check on the icon on the left. This means it's already installed

[image]

Comment: Not in 20.04 anymore :-( https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnash