# how do I play local swf files in firefox

Tags: swf

on ubuntu 14.04 forefox won't play swf even though flash is installed. 
I tried editing the mime type file and updated the mime databse and still get nothing.

Comment: So I assume you [saw this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7240/how-do-i-play-swf-files?rq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is to edit `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`

and change
`<mime-type type="application/vnd.adobe.flash.movie">`

to
`<mime-type type="application/x-shockwave-flash">`

Then run the command:

```
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

**This answer is quoted from answer in** [**ubuntuforums**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218732&page=2&p=13017544#post13017544)