# Problems opening .swf file

Tags: firefox, flash, swf

I am new to Ubuntu, running 16.04, so forgive me if I've overlooked something simple or obvious.  I've been on this thread [How do I play .swf files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7240/how-do-i-play-swf-files) but nothing there has worked for me.

I installed gnash but it only displays a blank screen when I try to play the .swf file.

I tried the Adobe Standalone Flash Player, but it only asks for a url.  I can't determine any way to play the .swf saved on the computer - the player is not an option under 'open with'

When I tried the Edit /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml file option, when I found that file, it opened in my firefox browser and I could not edit anything.

When I try to open the file directly with Firefox, it just asks what program I want to use to open it.  If I choose Firefox, it opens another tab with the same question, again and again.

VLC media player will not play the file.

What else can I do?

Comment: I had to really hunt for an .swf file, I wasn't aware anyone still used them. Anyway, I was able to play it in VLC 2.2.2 (right click+open with...). If you can, check in Tools --> Codec Information. My file was Audio - mp3, video - FLV1. The codecs used in your files may be the problem. Also, can you play .flv files?

Comment: VLC won't even recognize the file, I can't open it from VLC using Open Media, so I can't check the codec information.